# How can I integrate CallRail and Zoho CRM without Zapier?

Tags: integration, zoho

It's self-explanatory from the question but here's what my client wants.

They wanted me to integrate Zoho CRM and CallRail, I suggested about Zapier but for some reason they don't want to use Zapier and asking for any other way to integrate both.

I've searched about other software too mainly Zapier competitors such as Pabbly Connect and Workato.

But can anyone suggest me what should I use or is there any other way to integrate CallRail with Zoho CRM?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what data needs to be exchanged you might be able to implement the integration in Zoho CRM's Deluge coding language (https://www.zoho.com/deluge/help/) making calls to CallRail's api: (https://apidocs.callrail.com)

Zoho-Deluge's invokeurl command is the main functionality for making calls to CallRail's AP: https://www.zoho.com/deluge/help/webhook/invokeurl-api-task.html

This approach will require some work:

- set up the authentication between the two platforms
- all the data exchange behaviors

Answer (score 0):

I just checked the invoke URL page and the syntax is the following:

```
response = invokeUrl
]
url: <url_value> 
type: [<type_value>]
headers: [<headers_value>]
content-type: [<content_type_value>]
parameters: [<parameters_value>]
files: [<files_value>]
connection: [<connection_name>]
detailed: [<detailed_value>]
response-format: [<response_format_value>]
response-decoding: [<encoding_format_value>]
];
```

Could you guys share some tips about how to correctly customize this code? I know it has a lot to do with the data we want to pull from CallRail, but checking the CallRail library, it has a lot of variables, and having a better idea of which parameters would be recognized by Deluge would be useful.

Also, I was talking with some devs and they told me that it's required to know where the API call will be executed, is it recommended to rent a VPS or it can be done through any other Zoho tool like Creator?

Thanks